# How to improve digit recognition prediction in Neural Networks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I've made digit recognition (56x56 digits) using Neural Networks, but I'm getting 89.5% accuracy on test set and 100% on training set. I know that it's possible to get >95% on test set using this training set. Is there any way to improve my training so I can get better predictions? Changing iterations from 300 to 1000 gave me +0.12% accuracy. I'm also file size limited so increasing number of nodes can be impossible, but if that's the case maybe I could cut some pixels/nodes from the input layer.

To train I'm using:

- input layer: 3136 nodes
- hidden layer: 220 nodes
- labels: 36
- regularized cost function with lambda=0.1
- fmincg to calculate weights (1000 iterations)

Comment: What method do you use for training your network?

Comment: As I said in topic: [fmincg](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42770-logistic-regression-with-regularization-used-to-classify-hand-written-digits/content/Logistic%20Regression%20with%20regularisation/fmincg.m). It's like [fminunc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html), but people say it's better.

Comment: How did you come to those parameters? Are you using cross-validation?

Comment: Didn't use cross-validation. Input I've got from the number of pixels (56x56), hidden nodes is pretty random (wanted to get them from formula: sqrt(input*labels), but it was too high to fit in file size limit), lambda is random too (was choosing between: 1, 0.1, 0.01). And iterations - the more, the better or am I wrong?

Comment: I would use a large number for the iterations. Split my training data into at least 2 parts by 80% to 20%. Feed the first part to the network as training. Afterwards test the network with the second part (don't do any weight update) and calculate the error. Repeat this until your test error stops decreasing. Otherwise, if you just train the network with your training data until the error is at minimum, you will have an overfit.

Comment: What about training using 80% of the data, but calculating cost for all the data? Can that help? If not I'll try with that error.

Comment: Are you using a fully connected neural network? In that case a convolutional neural network will perform much better.

Comment: Yes. Its 3 layer NN. 1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output layer. I don't know how convolutional networks work. They're too complicated for me.

Comment: @Potato Unfortunately CNNs are the best for the task you are doing, a MLP is just not as good.

Comment: @Matias is right about CNN. If you have a fixed size for the input images CNNs can go above 95% on for example MNIST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the easiest and most promising way is to switch to a Convolutional Neural Network. But with you current model you can:

- Add more layers with less neurons each, which increases learning capacity and should increase accuracy by a bit. Problem is that you might start overfitting. Use regularization to counter this.
- Use [batch Normalization](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) (BN). While you are already using regularization, BN accelerates training and also does regularization, and is a NN specific algorithm that might work better.
- Make an ensemble. Train several NNs on the same dataset, but with a different initialization. This will produce slightly different classifiers and you can combine their output to get a small increase in accuracy.
- Cross-entropy loss. You don't mention what loss function you are using, if its not Cross-entropy, then you should start using it. All the high accuracy classifiers use cross-entropy loss.
- Switch to backpropagation and Stochastic Gradient Descent. I do not know the effect of using a different optimization algorithm, but backpropagation might outperform the optimization algorithm you are currently using, and you could combine this with other optimizers such as Adagrad or [ADAM](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980).
- Other small changes that might increase accuracy are changing the activation functions (like ReLU), shuffle training samples after every epoch, and do data augmentation.